# pandas plotting - sharex altering x values in plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm attempting to plot 3 subplots with a scatter plot at axes[0,0] a horizontal bar chart at axes[0,1] and a bar chart at axes[1,0]. The plots are working fine, except when I try to get them to share axes. Below is my code and a picture of the output:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(10,10))

df.plot(x=['LCScore'],
             y=['Retail Price (Value)'],
             s=bike_df['BV Total']/100,
             kind="scatter",
             ax=axes[0,0],
             alpha=0.5)
df.groupby('Retail Price (Value)')['BV Total'].sum().plot(y='BV Total',
                kind="barh",
                ax=axes[0,1],
                yticks=(80,100,120,140,160,180,200))
df.groupby('LCScore')['BV Total'].sum().plot(y='BV Total',
                kind="bar",
                ax=axes[1,0])
plt.sca(axes[0,0])
plt.xticks((1,2,3,4),('i','i','c','m'))
plt.sca(axes[1,0])
plt.xticks((1,2,3,4),('i','i','c','m'))
plt.show()
fig.savefig('foo.pdf')
plt.close()
```

[image]

It seems to be occurring when I'm assigning xticks to the axes[1,0] subplot.

Comment: Can you add the picture of the output?

Comment: @DavidG Yep, sorry about that.

Comment: pandas barplots start at 0. So you would want to have `plt.xticks((0,1,2,3),('i','i','c','m'))`.